# Python regular expression problem

Tags: python, regex

I need to do something in regex but I'm really not good at it, long time didn't do that .

```
/a/c/a.doc
```

I need to change it to

```
\\a\\c\\a.doc
```

Please trying to do it by using regular expression in Python.

Comment: Why do you need to change this? Python can do just fine with / as a path separator.

Answer (score 5):

I'm entirely in favor of helping user483144 distinguish "solution" from "regular expression", as the previous two answerers have already done.  It occurs to me, moreover, that **os.path.normpath()** http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html might be what he's *really* after.

Answer (score 2):

why do you think you every solution to your  problem needs regular expression??

```
>>> s="/a/c/a.doc"
>>> '\\'.join(s.split("/"))
'\\a\\c\\a.doc'
```

By the way, if you are going to change path separators, you may just as well use `os.path.join`

eg

```
mypath = os.path.join("C:\\","dir","dir1")
```

Python will choose the correct slash for you. Also, check out `os.sep` if you are interested.

Comment: it does not seem that the original poster believes that every solution needs regular expression.

Comment: @akonsu, almost all his previous posts are about regex.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it without regular expressions:

```
x = '/a/c/a.doc'
x = x.replace('/',r'\\')
```

But if you really want to use re:

```
x = re.sub('/', r'\\', x )
```

Comment: You can use a raw string to make this cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

`\\` is means `"\\"` or `r"\\"` ?

`re.sub(r'/', r'\\', 'a/b/c')`

use `r'....'` alwayse when you use regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

```
'\\\'.join(r'/a/c/a.doc'.split("/"))
```